# Publish Web does not include some dependency assemblies

Tags: mysql, wcf, web, dependencies, publish

In the past I have been using batch files to prepare release packages targeting different environments such as test, staging and production, and then copy the files to the Web site folders through various means. The batch files may run XmlPreProcess to alter web.config for different environments.

Lately I am trialing the Publish Web feature of VS 2012, after installing Web Deploy 3 in the server side. The result is looking good for Hello World.

However, I have a WCF app: MyWcfApp.dll had dependency on MyWcfContracts.dll and MyWcfImplementation.dll which depend on MyData.dll and MySql.Data.dll, yes, I am using MySql. All these files appear in the build folder, say MyWcfAp\bin\Debug.

When running Publish Web, I got some warning: The database provider for this connection string, MySql.Data.MySqlClient, is not supported for incremental database publishing. Incremental database publishing is supported only for SqlClient as well as Entity Framework Code First models.

Then the other dependent assemblies such as MySql.Data.dll got not copied over to the server.

Apparently Publish Web does a lot "smart" things through analyzing Web.config and having a lot presumptions.

Question 1:
Is it good to use Publish Web to deploy WCF service?

Question 2:
Is it possible to run some pre-deployment script say running XmlPreProcess before the deployment so I could target different environments?

Question 3:
Is it possible to ask Publish Web not to analyze Web.config and then just copy every assemblies and files in the build folder?

Answer (score 1):

For the specific issue (Question 3) of not copying over dependent-upon assemblies:

I am working with a small WCF Service Application that I am deploying to my local file system (then hosting the site in IIS) and had the problem of depended-upon assemblies not being copied to the local folder.  The solution for me had two steps:

- In the service's References, hi-light each reference you need to be copied and hit F4.  In the new window make sure 'Copy Local' is set to 'true'.
- Right click on the Service Project and select properties.  Click the 'Package/Publish Web' section, and from the 'Items to deploy...' dropdown select 'All files in this project folder'.